# Animating (sliding) a view with content created in drawRect:

Tags: ios, animation, calayer

I have some views that have content, textures and shadows mostly, that need to be moved by sliding them to another part of the screen.

These textures are created in drawRect: and only need to be rendered once in the life of the view (with the possible exception of optionally recolouring them).

However, the slide is a little jerky, aI assume this is because the texture keeps being redrawn.

I was wondering if there is any value in rendering the texture by directly using the views CALayer. Will this avoid the texture being re rendered whenever the view moves?

I have never used CALayer before.

thanks
karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override drawRect and use your view like that, it'll be redraw every time. What you can do is create a method that draw your view once and that is being called once (let's say after init) and don't override drawRect. That should fix your performance issue.

One more thing, every view are backed by a layer (CALayer), if you do animation and you want better performance you should move the layer instead of moving his view (UIView) during animation. To access the layer of a view, just do myView.layer.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: No problem, if you are satisfy, you can click and give me some little reputation :)